# java regex expression giving output off by 1

Tags: java, regex

**Background:**

I am attempting to regex registry paths and break it into hive, key, subkey, value, and data. So far I have gotten a regex for key to work but I am having issues getting to subkey successfully.

**question:**

what in my regex is making it display the "m\"? and what should i be doing instead to only collect everything after the first slash?

**regex being tested:**

```
(?<subkeyName>[^\\](\\.*)+$)
```

**Example data:**

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\LsaPid
```

**What I am seeing as results:**

```
M\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\LsaPid
```

**desired output:**

```
System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\LsaPid
```

regex tester I am using:
https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output

**solution and why:**

```
\\\\(?<subkeyName>.*)
```

The issue ended up being that the interpreter my application is using on the backend requires specific special characters to be escaped. the solution provided by @revo was correct if used in normal context and i have marked it as such.

Comment: The `[^\\]` captures every character that isn't \, in your case `M`. Try `(?<subkeyName>(?:[^\\]\\)(.*)$)`

Comment: What you should see as result?

Comment: @revo i should be seeing "System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\LsaPid"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what in my regex is making it display the "m\"?

`[^\\]` part.

> what should i be doing instead to only collect everything after the
>   first slash?

Remove it:

```
\\(?<subkeyName>.*)
```

Comment: I believe this is pretty close to what I was trying to do. I tossed it through a few different online regex testers and they are showing me that match group 0 includes the leading \ and group 1 includes everything after that. Is that what you are seeing too?

Comment: With your own regex? No. With mine? for sure.

Comment: that was posted before i accepted you solution. i should have responded to it and clarified but the issue ended up being that the interpreter my application is using on the backend requires specific special characters to be escaped. the solution provided by you was correct if used in normal context and i have marked it as such. i ended up having to double escape all the \ to get my application to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The `[^\\]` captures every character that isn't `\`, in your case it's `M`.

Using [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/rNPrVh/1), this code should help you capture everything after the first slash:

```
String regex = "(?<subkeyName>(?:[^\\\\]\\\\)(.*)$)";
String input = "HKLM\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Lsa\\LsaPid";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
m.find();
String result = m.group(2);
```

Comment: I tried out this regex and I am getting back "No match found". I added to the description the regex tester I am using to test with. Is there a better one I should be using for testing of these regex? thanks!

Comment: @toosweetnitemare Did you try to compile it in a Java code? The slash escaping can cause weird results with online regex testers

Comment: i was able to use revo's solution successfully. for some reason, the application interpreter we have to use kept failing on the regex you posted with a generic error. I was unable to get more verbose output unfortunately so i can't even troubleshoot it further. thank you very much for your help!